# Gem installation fails from custom repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Wanted to install a gem from custom gem repo. Here are the steps which i followed
 1. Created a gem and copied it to `gems` folder under `gems_repo`.
 2. Run the command `gem generate_index`. This command created some files. I copied the files to `http://example.com` Attaching a screen shot of the same.
 [image] 
After running the command to install the gem , it gave me following error

```
gem install some_gem_name --source 'http://example.com/gems_repo'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'some_gem_name' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://example.com/gems_repo/ - server did not return a valid file (http://example.com/gems_repo/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I have tried `gem update --system` command and tried to install the gem again. It gave the same error as above. If you look at the screen shot the file for which the command is complaining is already there.

The ruby version is `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]` and `gem -v = 2.6.10`

Can you please help me fix this error

Comment: Can you access in browser http://example.com/gems_repo/specs.4.8.gz ? Maybe it is permission issue?

Comment: Yes . I can access it.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/840) is causing this